# Printer turns on whenever a USB-stick is plugged into my Linux pc, but not in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, usb, printer

As the headline states, I have a question about this phenomenon. Whenever i plug in a random USB-stick into a random USB-port on my Linux laptop, my printer begins to move its insides around. This happens every time I plug it in. I have a different computer on the same network running Windows 10, however, nothing happens to the printer when I plug in a USB-stick in that machine, nor any other device that I have tried. Furthermore, this thing happens the second I plug it in, even before i write the mount command. Can anyone enlighten me on this behaviour? It seems very strange.

This output is taken directly from journalctl:

```
Command: journalctl --since "2019-06-28 15:00:00"

-- Logs begin at Sun 2018-01-28 16:58:17 CET, end at Tue 2019-05-28 17:44:19 CEST. --
-- No entries --
```

This is the dmesq output after i have plugged an USB in and out several times:

```
Command: dmesg

[342423.846402]  sdb: sdb1
[342423.855949] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[342492.677063] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 68
[342512.983535] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 69 using xhci_hcd
[342513.135137] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=3100
[342513.135140] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[342513.135142] usb 1-1: Product: STORE N GO
[342513.135144] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[342513.135145] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 07B40B08943D8FBB
[342513.135582] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[342513.136825] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[342514.180457] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[342514.181036] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[342515.900508] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 15646720 512-byte logical blocks: (8.01 GB/7.46 GiB)
[342515.904270] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[342515.904275] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[342515.908022] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[342515.908032] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[342515.938679]  sdb: sdb1
[342515.947882] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[342819.613569] python2[17356]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f86d41d4e4a sp 00007ffe571435c0 error 4 in libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.32[7f86d417c000+b0000]
[343061.089108] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 69
[343674.493639] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 70 using xhci_hcd
[343674.649304] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=3100
[343674.649310] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[343674.649314] usb 1-1: Product: STORE N GO
[343674.649317] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[343674.649320] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 07B40B08943D8FBB
[343674.650025] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[343674.650733] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[343675.710754] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[343675.711348] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[343677.455222] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 15646720 512-byte logical blocks: (8.01 GB/7.46 GiB)
[343677.459010] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[343677.459015] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[343677.462723] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[343677.462732] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[343677.494533]  sdb: sdb1
[343677.503280] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[343738.750009] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 70
```

Comment: Does the printer behave like this when you unplug and plug it back in? Yes: Are the USB ports all adjacent to each other or spread around the casing? Adjacent: Possible faulty connection to USB hardware causing the printer to think its being unplugged and reconnected.

Comment: First step is to look at `dmesg` or the syslog (journalctl for systemd) to have a look what the system think it is doing. The printing subsystem may try to scan for new printers when new USB devices are added, and during this process may (wrongly) initialize your printer again for some reason, and initializing it may cause it to "move its insides around".

Comment: Okay, so I have had a  look at it and nothing springs to mind. I am only able to see that the USB is connecting properly as it should. The output as I plug it in only gives me information about the USB itself, nothing about network or simular. I tried to look at both dmesg and journalctl. Any ideas now?

Comment: I have added the output to the original post.